# iftop Shows Lots of Mysterious Connections - Not Showing in netstat

Tags: ubuntu, networking, connection, linux-networking, netstat

I've just stopped all pretty much all services except sshd on my server (Ubuntu Server 10.04), and when I run iftop I get output that looks like this:

```
                 12.5Kb            25.0Kb           37.5Kb            50.0Kb      62.5Kb
└────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────
flash.gateway.2wire.net:ssh   <=> 172.16.1.151:60405             1.75Kb  1.54Kb  2.22Kb
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 69.127.29.20:32582              536b    107b     27b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 190.164.122.134:13557             0b    105b     26b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 79.165.212.195:45138              0b    105b     26b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 151.42.15.151:9031                0b     72b     18b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 88.185.120.179:51413              0b      0b     49b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 178.120.152.97:25924              0b      0b     29b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 109.110.217.77:27868              0b      0b     26b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 84.13.201.90:16509                0b      0b     26b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 171.7.125.224:11777               0b      0b     26b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 115.177.164.170:21360             0b      0b     26b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 50.88.126.18:25540                0b      0b     25b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 223.206.230.163:13431             0b      0b     25b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 78.144.187.26:24515               0b      0b     25b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 83.20.61.211:27572                0b      0b     25b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 82.134.151.42:18448               0b      0b     18b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 126.117.95.247:25316              0b      0b     18b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 116.202.65.230:9044               0b      0b     18b
flash.gateway.2wire.net:21095 <=> 88.120.63.205:51413               0b      0b     17b
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
TX:             cumm:  61.6KB   peak:   8.00Kb          rates:   1.59Kb  1.38Kb  2.04Kb
RX:                    18.4KB           1.64Kb                    696b    549b    640b
TOTAL:                 80.0KB           9.64Kb                   2.27Kb  1.92Kb  2.66Kb
```

This is the first part (not the unix socket part) of the output of netstat -a:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:55677                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 flash.gateway.2wire:ssh 172.16.1.151:60405      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0     48 flash.gateway.2wire:ssh 172.16.1.151:60661      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
udp        0      0 *:37790                 *:*
```

What could all those strange connections on port 21095 be? And why would they not show up in netstat?? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this server configured as a gateway (just guessing by the domainname) and uses IPTables to NAT, or something like that? So maybe tis is another host connecting through you.

Comment: @ChristopherPerrin the hostname is "flash," the 
"gateway.2wire.net" is a domain that many home routers push to DHCP clients.

Comment: @JoelESalas I know that but still it could have been a clue. Asking doesn't hurt ;)

Comment: @ChristopherPerrin No, it's not a gateway, I don't even think routing is enabled. I will check that tomorrow morning, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

[`iftop`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iftop) looks at all packets going through the interface using [pcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) (packet capture).

[`netstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) shows sockets on the machines.

Any packet that’s forwarded to another host will appear in the former, not the latter.

Looks like all of the packets found to port `21095` were almost alone. It could be failing connection attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Those are most certainly failed connection attempts. Check out with `tcpdump`; you should see them along with your host's ICMP port unreachable (since you don't have anything listening on that port):

```
01:58:31.471535 IP some.remote.host.24053 > your.local.host.21095: UDP, length 35
01:58:31.472006 IP your.local.host > some.remote.host: ICMP your.local.host udp port 21095 unreachable, length 71
```

(example supposing it's UDP)